# Displaying Current User in view through a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby, authentication, polymorphic-associations

I am attempting to display the current users name once they are logged in.

Therefore at the top of the page it would say "Logged in as Patrick". However I have a polymorphic association set up whereby every user that signs up is either a player or a coach.

The polymorphic association is under the label or :tennis_player as both coach and player play tennis.

The code for the view is below.

```
    <div class="container">
    <header>

    <div class="logo">
        <%= link_to(image_tag 'tennis_ball.png', :width => 100, :height => 100) %>
    </div>
    <div class="slogan">
        <h3>Setfortennis</h3>
    </div>


  <div id="user_nav">
    <% if current_user? %>
        Logged in as <%= @current_user %>

        <%= link_to "log out", log_out_path %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", sign_up_path %> or
        <%= link_to "Log in", log_in_path %>
    <% end %>
</div>

    </header>
</div>
```

Here is my application controller

```
    helper_method :current_user?

  before_filter :get_user

  def current_user?
    !!current_user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= session[:user_id] &&
      User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end

  def check_logged_in
    redirect_to( new_session_path, :notice => "You must be logged in to do that!") unless current_user?
  end

  def get_user
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

And here are my models. Anything else needed to solve let me know!

```
    class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :about, :club, :first_name, :last_name, :profile_picture, :racket, :ranking, :image

  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }

  has_many :videos

  has_one :user, :as => :tennis_player

end


  class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :about, :club, :first_name, :last_name, :profile_picture, :ranking

  has_one :user, :as => :tennis_player
end
```

User Model.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password_hash, :password_salt, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password

  belongs_to :tennis_player, :polymorphic => true

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_confirmation_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :password

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user 
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is in your User model?

Comment: Hello Konstantin,

I have added my User model above. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't getting, does current_user.tennis_player.last_name works in your view?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the right id whenever you create a session. But I would change the design a little. Instead of having two separate tables for Player and Coach, you can create a base class User, and inherit from it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :about, :club, :first_name, :last_name, :profile_picture, :ranking
end

class Player < User
end

class Coach < User
end
```